# RESTful model for get-or-create route

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

What's the most RESTful way to model an API which acts mostly as a GET, except that if the resource doesn't exist it creates it before returning it?

I can imagine using GET, although GET isn't supposed to change server state. I can also imagine using PUT, but in this case the resource should be immutable and PUT implies that the resource should be updated if it already exists. It can certainly be POST, but I feel like POST is the overused hammer to all impedance mismatch nails between API modeling and RESTful modeling.

Or should it be split into two separate routes outright? But that seems unnecessarily inefficient.

What's the consensus?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, it is implemented as follows:
GET:Reads resource
POST:Creates resource
PUT:Updates resource
DELETE:Deletes resource

The common issue seems to be that get is limited on query string args.  If you run against this limit, you may want to consider using custom headers.  In either case, I would recommend that you follow the verb translations above.

Also, you don't mention the language.  There is probably a framework that you can leverage that would abstract a lot of this from you.

Comment: I intentionally don't mention a language or framework since the answer should be about REST itself, and the implications of RESTful design. If I interpret your answer correctly, then basically you're suggesting to split it into GET and POST. Given the common-ness of a GetOrCreate-style API, I was hoping there's a more efficient but still RESTful way of doing this.

Comment: REST isn't defined by HTTP verbs.  It is about treating resources as nouns with state.  You use verbs to manage those resources.  With that said, the HTTP verbs have become synonymous with the CRUD verbs as stated.  Can you do it differently and be REST?  Yes.  However, you would definitely be going against the grain.